# Is this a memory leak? Pls check code below

Tags: .net, vb.net, memory-leaks

In my VB application I use Datasets as follows:

```
Dim rs As DataSet
Dim sql As String = "some sql"
rs = GetDataSet(sql, db)
' Work with the data

sql = "another sql"
rs = GetDataSet(sql, db)
' More code

rs.Dispose
```

Will this cause memory leak if I add a dispose at the end of the sub or should I dispose rs after every usage of it?

Comment: No, it's not a leak. The garbage collector will take care of cleaning up unused objects.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Please don't use the words "garbage collector" and "disposing of" in the same sentence like that, they're different things. The garbage collector never *disposes of* anything. It only collects. It *may* end up calling the finalizer of an object, and that finalizer might end up calling Dispose, but that's still not the garbage collectors duty to do. There's enough confusion on SO about the duties of the garbage collector and disposable objects, let's not contribute more to that confusion.

Comment: This is most likely not a leak. If `GetDataSet`, of which we know nothing about, stores a reference to the returned data set somewhere, it *may* be a leak, but if it simply constructs the new object and returns it, then no, it will not be a leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem with "memory leaks" is that in .NET they are not the same as they are in languages with direct memory management (like C/C++). In .NET leaked memory is almost always is a result of referencing the object from one of the garbage collector roots caused by badly managed dependencies between the object in the graph, not by missing memory deallocation.

Technically, there is nothing wrong with not disposing a disposable object and the application can even work quite well not calling Dispose at all.

While I have a few nice examples of the .NET memory leaks in my article, http://alexatnet.com/articles/memory-leaks-in-net-applications, it is missing one trivial example - missing Dispose in a case when object data consists of two parts - tiny managed wrapper around the massive array of unmanaged data (in other words, something like images). Imagine that application creates several images and do not dispose them when they are no longer required. In this case GC will not collect garbage and destroy images as the GC threshold is not being hit and images quickly consume all available virtual memory and crash the application.

Consider the opposite - quite large .NET object and tiny unmanaged resource like small COM object. In this case even if the Disposed is not called explicitly, intensive use of these object will call GC often enough to clean up all the objects that are not disposed manually and you will never have OutOfMemory exception.

This is why it is hard to tell if your code example contains the "memory leak" or, to be more precise, will it cause troubles?

The example itself is not accurate and it is quite clear that the first object is not disposed. If it consists mostly of managed objects, it will not cause troubles - the code just does not look good. If it is has significant amount of unmanaged data (BLOBS or something) then it may eventually crash your application.

So if you want to be sure, rewrite it with "using" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/htd05whh.aspx. If you like exreme and consider your life being too plain without working late debugging OutOfMemory issues - just keep it as it is.

Sorry for long answer for such simple question.